# Dropdown menu AdapterView.OnItemClickListener not invoked

Tags: kotlin, drop-down-menu, onclicklistener

Why is the OnItemClickListener not being invoked and how can I store the selection?

I would like to create an autocomplete dropdown menu and then move to the next page the value saved but the listener doesn't show the text within that I wrote in the log.

Is there something missing? What should I add?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val countries = resources.getStringArray(R.array.countrylist)
        val autoComp : AutoCompleteTextView = findViewById(id.autoComtv_SelectCountry)
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.dropdown_countries, countries)
        autoComp.setAdapter(adapter)

        Log.d("hey", autoComp.text.toString())

        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {adapterView,view,i,l->
            val itemSelected:String = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString()
            Log.d("hey", "test") //doesn't show on console after picking country
            Log.d("hey", autoComp.text.toString()) //doesn't show
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item: $itemSelected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```